# How to make label be aligned on the right side?

Tags: pine-script

In a pivot points script, the S1, R1, etc. labels are on the left side of the lines, by default.  How do I make it so that S1 label is on the right side of the line, instead of left side (which it now)

`label.new(bar_index, s1Level, "S1", style=label.style_none)`

The full code for the script here below:

```
//@version=4
study("Pivot Points Standard", shorttitle="Pivots Std", overlay=true)
higherTF = input("D", type=input.resolution)
prevCloseHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, close[1], lookahead=true)
prevOpenHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, open[1], lookahead=true)
prevHighHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead=true)
prevLowHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead=true)

pLevel = (prevHighHTF + prevLowHTF + prevCloseHTF) / 3
r1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevLowHTF
s1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevHighHTF

var line r1Line = na
var line pLine = na
var line s1Line = na

if pLevel[1] != pLevel
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_extend(r1Line, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(pLine, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(s1Line, extend.none)
    r1Line := line.new(bar_index, r1Level, bar_index, r1Level, extend=extend.right)
    pLine := line.new(bar_index, pLevel, bar_index, pLevel, width=3, extend=extend.right)
    s1Line := line.new(bar_index, s1Level, bar_index, s1Level, extend=extend.right)
    label.new(bar_index, r1Level, "R1", style=label.style_none)
    label.new(bar_index, pLevel, "P", style=label.style_none)
    label.new(bar_index, s1Level, "S1", style=label.style_none)

if not na(pLine) and line.get_x2(pLine) != bar_index
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we use the same technique used to extend the lines, but with the label:

```
//@version=4
study("Pivot Points Standard", shorttitle="Pivots Std", overlay=true)
higherTF = input("D", type=input.resolution)
prevCloseHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, close[1], lookahead=true)
prevOpenHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, open[1], lookahead=true)
prevHighHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead=true)
prevLowHTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead=true)

pLevel = (prevHighHTF + prevLowHTF + prevCloseHTF) / 3
r1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevLowHTF
s1Level = pLevel * 2 - prevHighHTF

var line r1Line = na
var line pLine = na
var line s1Line = na
var label r1Label = na
var label pLabel  = na
var label s1Label = na

if pLevel[1] != pLevel
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_extend(r1Line, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(pLine, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(s1Line, extend.none)
    r1Line := line.new(bar_index, r1Level, bar_index, r1Level, extend=extend.right)
    pLine := line.new(bar_index, pLevel, bar_index, pLevel, width=3, extend=extend.right)
    s1Line := line.new(bar_index, s1Level, bar_index, s1Level, extend=extend.right)
    r1Label := label.new(bar_index, r1Level, "R1", style=label.style_none)
    pLabel  := label.new(bar_index, pLevel, "P", style=label.style_none)
    s1Label := label.new(bar_index, s1Level, "S1", style=label.style_none)

if not na(pLine) and line.get_x2(pLine) != bar_index
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index)
    label.set_x(r1Label, bar_index)
    label.set_x(pLabel, bar_index)
    label.set_x(s1Label, bar_index)
```

[image]